# Determine function using given sequence

Tags: functions

It is given that f(x) is a continous function and f(0)=2

$f(x)-f(x/23)=x/23$

How can I find f(484)

This is how far I got Using replacement

$f(x)-f(x/23^n)=x/23 + x/23^2 .......x/23^n$

I guess this would result in some series but I'm not able to get to the answer

Comment: I don't understand how you got what you claimed to get via "replacement".  I note that, replacing $x$ with $\frac {x}{23}$ we get $f\left( \frac x{23}\right)-f\left(\frac x{23^2}\right)=\frac x{23^2}$ and adding to the original we get $f(x)-f\left(\frac x{23^2}\right)=\frac x{23}+\frac x{23^2}$, for example.

Comment: @lulu I meant that we do this this for n terms and add all which results in this

Comment: Ok.  Well, what happens if we fix $x$ but let $n$ tend to $\infty$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by @lulu

$F(x)=f(x/23^n)+x/23 +x/23^2+x/23^3.......$

For n tending to infinity

$F(x)=f(0)+x/23(1-x/23)$

Answer (score 0):

Let's start from the relation
$$
f(x) - f(\alpha x) = \alpha x\,,
\qquad \text{with}\ \alpha\in (0,1)
$$
(In your case $\alpha = 1/23$.)

For every $n\in\mathbb{N}$, $n\geq 1$, it holds that
$$
f(x) - f(\alpha^n x) = \sum_{k=1}^n [f(\alpha^{k-1} x) - f(\alpha^k x)]
= \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha^k x = \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha} (1-\alpha^n) \, x.
$$
Passing to the limit as $n\to \infty$, and taking into account that $f$ is continuous (only continuity at the origin is needed), we get
$$
f(x) - f(0) = \frac{\alpha}{1-\alpha}\, x\,.
$$